# How I can filter the relation of a model in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Category model `hasmany` products relation which product model has `type` relation.

in View, I can get the product of a category and its type.

```
$categories = Category::with('products.type')->get();
return $categories->find(3)->products->find(2)->type;
```

but I want to query in `controller` base on `type`. and I don't know how to query based on type `request`.

I mean:

```
$type = $request('type');
```

and return `Category` that `product` `type` is $type;

Comment: it seems the column doesn't exist in the category table as the error said,did you recently add a new migration with the "type" column and run it?

Comment: check my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884218/how-to-show-categories-that-its-products-relation-have-a-specific-attribute/68894049#68894049

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using the relationship method if you defined it in Category model

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

So then you can manage the relationship query like:

```
$categories = Category::all();
$products_type = $categories->products()->where('type', $this->type)->get();
```