# How to show categories that it's products relation have a specific attribute?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The `Category` model `hasMany` `Products` that `belongsTo` a `Category`, the `products` table have `category_id` and `type` columns.

I need to show just the `categories` whose products' type have a specific value.

I tried this but didn't get the correct results:

```php
return Category::with('products')->get()->filter(function ($query) {
    return $query->products
        ->where('type_id', 1);
    // or return $query->products->contain('type_id', 1);
});
```

Comment: Try 100% to avoid `->get()->filter()`  and have a `where` inside the `filter` as you are getting **ALL** models, you could be getting 100k models so you will be timing out because out of memory or would take forever... You write that filter condition as a where before getting the data, DB is 100000000% more performant for this type of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method :

```
$typeId = 1;
Category::with('products')->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($typeId) {
    return $query->where('type_id', $typeId);
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you but didn't work, this shows the categories that its products have that type_id 1 also 2,3 and... I need to filter the categories and just get the products with type_id = 1

Comment: change `$typeId = 1;` to `$typeId = "1";`, hope it will work

Comment: I tried this and show me just the products not categories:
    return Category::with('products')->get()->flatMap(function ($q){
       return $q->products->where('type_id', 1);
    });

Comment: even I changed the type_id column to type with string values as "small, "big" and ... but can't get what I need. 
    return  Category::with('products')->whereHas('products', function ($query) {
            return $query->where('type', "small");
        })->get();

Answer (score 0):

I found the working Answer:

```
    return Category::with(['products' => function ($q) {
        return $q->where('type', "small");
    }])->whereHas('products')->get();
```